# How to reduce my code in both jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#news").hover(function () {
            $('#news_img').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 290, function () {
            });
        });

        $("#news1").hover(function () {
            $('#news_img1').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 290, function () {
            });
        });

        $("#news3").hover(function () {
            $('#news_img3').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 290, function () {
            });
        });

        $("#news4").hover(function () {
            $('#news_img4').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 290, function () {
            });
        });
    });
```

**JSFIDDLE** here:
**http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/N89Kw/**

I would like to reduce my code and make it easier to manage in the future whenever I would love to add more `<tr>` or `<td>` tags without editing too much in the jQuery and CSS.

Comment: place your code in the question.

Comment: Just jQuery code would be enough!

Comment: OK. This has fixed already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the hover elements by its class `news` and find the target element by appending the last digits in the hovered element's id to `news_img` like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".news").hover(function () {
        $('#news_img' + this.id.replace('news', '')).stop(true).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 290, function () {});
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fz5eL/)

---

You can remove the css part of the hover by adding some data-* attributes to the image like

```
<img src="http://i853.photobucket.com/albums/ab100/vimeo1903/Showroom1_zps923b43dc.jpg" border="0" alt="Showroom1" data-hover="http://i853.photobucket.com/albums/ab100/vimeo1903/Showroom1_1_zpse41d0851.jpg" />
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //since the news elements has a common class, use it to target all the news elements instead of using individual ids
    $(".news").hover(function (e) {
        //you can find the `news_img` within the current news item using .find() instead of using its class to target it
        $(this).find('.news_img').stop(true).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 290);
        //find the image element within the current news
        var $img = $(this).find('.imgswap img');
        //if the current event is mouseenter then show the hover image else the src image
        //the hover handler registers 2 handler one for mouseenter another for mouseleave
        $img.attr('src', $img.data(e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hover' : 'src'));
    });
    //when we leaves the news elements we need to put back the original src, so store it using data api
    $('.news .imgswap img').each(function () {
        $(this).data('src', this.src);
    })
});
```

Comment: That works well. However, I am wondering about your code and **Lloyd Banks**'s code, which one will help me to optimize the server?

Comment: @PMay1903 also see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fz5eL/2/ - it stream lines the hover image to be added to the image element itself instead of creating a new css style

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: Your last updated code is petty nice and I don't need to add anything to CSS as **my Title**. Those are what I am looking for. I appreciate all your help and **Lloyd Banks**.

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: Could you please add comments to your code in order to make it clear?

Comment: **1**. `$img.attr('src', $img.data(e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'hover' : 'src'));` **2**. `$(this).data('src', this.src);`--> These make me so confused...

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: Both of updated 3 and 4 are useful to me. If you have any changes or any news, please let me know about that. Thank you again for your great code and your additional comments.

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: Oppp! I have tested it already. However, there is a problem with the toggle that whenever you drag your mouse over the 4 images as quick as possible. The toggle then will get into a trouble that it doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: @PMay1903 is it reproducible in the fiddle - which part of the toggle? the image toggle or the text

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: The text doesn't go up anymore. As I thought, there is a crash bettween the `stop(true).animate()` with `hide` and `show`. Anyway I had tested again your first updated. That works very well but I need to remove the additional code in CSS.

Comment: @PMay1903 the first version and the 3/4 version are the same... not able to reproduce the problem here

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: As I thought, they are not the same because of the removing `#imgswap` in the CSS. In the first updated, you didn't remove anything the CSS. However, the updated 3 and 4 which had the improvement. As a result, this improvement might caused the problem...

Comment: @PMay1903 those css rules don't have anything to do with the text element... that is what is worrying me... are you able to recreate the issue in fiddle consistently

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: Sorry for this inconvenience but I don't know what problem I am facing with... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sL9sLRkPlzk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: what is the jQuery verison or any other libraries used

Comment: **@Arun P Johny**: That's correct, I have used the jQuery version 1.7.1. Therefore, it caused the problem and I can solve this with the newest version - 1.11. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute selector in jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^=news]").hover(function () {
                $('#news_img').stop().animate({
                    height: 'toggle'
                }, 290, function () {
                });
    });
 });
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/N89Kw/3/)

Comment: which toggle Please look at the fiddle and check let me know

Comment: This doesn't operate on a different news_img for each one like the OP's code.

Comment: All **toggle** for each image. Please take look on my JSFiddle and mouse over to each image, you will see the toggle goes up.

Comment: sorry i missed the braces

Comment: It's great. You are giving me one more choice for my code and it would be useful so much!

Comment: I eager to post the answer as a first person so i missed those things. Now i realized thanks @PMay1903

Answer (score 2):

Combine your jQuery calls into one function family.  Instead of 4 separate `.hover()` calls, use  class names and do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".news").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".news_img").animate({
            height: "toggle"
        }, 290, function(){
        });
    });
});
```

On your CSS, you're pretty compact already and there's really not much more you can do to reduce the amount of code you have.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N89Kw/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your code. Please let me know that your code with **find** will help my server running faster than the **Arun P Johny**'s **replace**?